Tight Jordan curve around a simply connected compact subset of the plane
Let $K\subset\mathbb C$ be compact and simply connected, and let $\varepsilon>0$. Does there exist a Jordan curve $\gamma$ such that $K$ is in the interior of $\gamma$ and for each $z\in\partial K$, we have $\operatorname{dist}(z,\gamma)<\varepsilon$? Intuitively, I  need a "tight" curve around $K$.
The problem can be simplified a bit (I think) by considering, instead of $K$, the compact set $\overline{K+\frac\varepsilon2\,\mathbb D}$, which is the closure of its interior. I also thought of covering $K$ with finitely many small balls and somehow joining the outside boundaries of the disk. Comments to my other question seem to imply that this approach has issues.

I think it was asked earlier (I remember answering) and the answer is positive (an application of Sard's theorem).

As phrased, it seems the Warsaw circle maybe causes problems? You can take the circle and add a little line segment on the "inside" of it, and that will be far from your "outside" curve $\gamma$.
https://wildtopology.com/bestiary/warsaw-circle/
If you switch the distance requirement around and say you want $d(z,K) < \varepsilon$ for all $z \in \gamma$, this problem goes away, and still to me seems to satisfy the desired intuitive requirement.

That sounds like a good answer, @BrandonduPreez

Thanks, I'll post it as a full response.

If you take the Warsaw / Polish circle (a topologists sine curve closed up to a circle), and attach a line segment to the interior of the circle, then the points of that line segment will be far away from any curve $\gamma$ you try wrap around the exterior (see the awful drawing below, and the following link for details on the warsaw circle https://wildtopology.com/bestiary/warsaw-circle/).

This gives you a compact, simply connected counterexample. So we can't have $\gamma$ wrap around the boundary.
But if you don't need $\gamma$ being close to all of the boundary, and only need that all of $\gamma$ is close to the boundary, this may not be a problem. I think the easiest fix may be to require $d(z, K) < \varepsilon$ for all $z \in \gamma$, rather than $d(z, \gamma) < \varepsilon$ for all $z \in K$. This condition still asks for a curve that wraps around $K$, but $K$ is allowed some holes.

You must invoke the fact that the Warsaw circle divides the plane in a (bounded)  interior and an (unbounded) exterior region. This is well-known, but should be explicitly mentioned.

Brandon du Preez gave an example showing that the answer to your question is negative. However, there is a positive result:
Let $K$ be a compact connected subset of the plane and $\epsilon > 0$ Then there exists a Jordan curve $\gamma$ such that $K$ is in the interior of $\gamma$ and $d(z,K) < \epsilon$ for all $z \in \gamma$.
Here is a sketch.
Consider a plane grid of horizontal lines having distance $\epsilon/4$ and vertical lines having distance $\epsilon/4$. It divides the plane into squares. Let $X$ denote the union of all squares intersecting $K$ (there are only finitely many of them). $X$ is a finite polyhedron. It is connected (otherwise $K$ would contain points in different components of $X$, thus $K$ would not be connected). Choose a regular PL-neighborhood $N$ of $X$ contained in the open-$\epsilon/4$-neighborhood of $X$. This requires a bit PL-topology. See for example

Rourke, Colin P., and Brian Joseph Sanderson. Introduction to piecewise-linear topology. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

$N$ is a compact two-dimensional PL-manifold with boundary. Its (finitely many) boundary components are compact one-dimensional PL-manifolds without boundary, i.e. PL circles $C_1,\ldots, C_n$. Each $z \in C_i$ has a distance $< \epsilon$ from $K$ (note that each point of $N$ has a distance $< \epsilon$ from $K$). None of the $C_i$ intersects $K$ (since $K$ is contained in $X$ and $X$ is contained in the interior of $N$).
We claim that $K$ is contained in the interior $I_k$ of some $C_k$; this is the desired Jordan curve.
Consider $C_1$. If $K$ is contained in the interior $I_1$ of $C_1$, we are done. If not, $K$ is contained in the interior of the PL-manifold $X_1= X \cup I_1$ with boundary circles $C_2, \ldots, C_n$. Proceed inductively. Either the process stops at some $C_k$ with $k < n$ (i.e. we have $K \subset I_k$) or goes to $k = n$. At this step we know that $K$ is contained in the interior of the PL-manifold $X_{n-1}= X \cup I_1 \cup \ldots \cup I_{n-1}$ which has the single boundary circle $C_n$. This means that $K \subset I_n$.
